# WITH clause containing a data-modifying statement must be at the top level SQL-state: 0A000

Tags: postgresql

I wrote function, which using WITH construction with insert into table like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func()
RETURNS json AS
$BODY$
begin
 return (
   with t as (
     insert into t(id) 
     select 1
     returning *
    )
 select '{"a":"a"}'::json
 );
end;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
select test_func()
```

Thats return error:

```
ERROR: WITH clause containing a data-modifying statement must be at the top level
SQL-состояние: 0A000
```

If execute

```
   with t as (
     insert into t(id) 
     select 1
     returning *
    )
 select '{"a":"a"}'::json
```

Result without errors.
Why this take place and how get round this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing subselect on that query, with is why it doesn't work.
This won't work either:

```
select * from (
   with t as (
     insert into t(id) 
     select 10
     returning *
    )
 select '{"a":"a"}'::json
) as sub
```

There are a few solutions to this.

a) Declare it as returning `setof` and use `return query`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func()
RETURNS setof json AS
$BODY$
begin
return query
   with t as (
     insert into t(id) 
     select 7
     returning *
    )
 select '{"a":"a"}'::json;
end;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

b) Declare it as `language sql`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func()
RETURNS json AS
$BODY$
   with t as (
     insert into t(id) 
     select 8
     returning *
    )
 select '{"a":"a"}'::json;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

c) Declare output variable(s) in argument list and assign result to them

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(OUT my_out_var json)
AS
$BODY$
begin
   with t as (
     insert into t(id) 
     select 9
     returning *
    )
 select '{"a":"a"}'::json INTO my_out_var;
end;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```